# Adding item into listview1 and remove if the item has already in the listview1 or replace

Tags: vb.net

I have `listview1` with 2 columns. I already have a code for adding items but my problem is when I add again the same item in `listview1`, it shows duplicates and when I continue to add the same item, the items in listview are increasing with same data.

Example for what I need:

When `listview1` has already a data in 1st column = 1 and in 2nd column = A, and I want to add again with a data like these 1st column = 1 and in 2nd column = B. I have 2 solutions and I try to code it but with no luck. My 2 solutions is these:

1. I just want to update only the data in 2nd column, from "A" to "B" but with the same 1st column data and no additional item will be added into listview like nothing just update/replace it.

OR

2. Remove the item that will cause duplication and add the same item so there will be no duplicates.

Here's my code for adding item:

```
 Private Sub rbChoiceA_Checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim rbA As RadioButton = TryCast(sender, RadioButton)
    Dim str As String = rbA.Parent.Name
    str = str.Remove(0, 6)
    lab1.Text = str
    Dim item As ListViewItem
    Dim row As String() = New String(2) {}
    row(0) = str
    row(1) = rbA.Text
    item = New ListViewItem(row)
    ListView1.Items.Add(item)

End Sub
```

I just need help to add the code for my problem. Your answers is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want help getting the "solutions" to work, post *that* code.  We cant help fix what we cant see

Comment: In any case you need to 'search' the current collection of ListViewItem to _Find_ if the Item with the specific value in column one exists or not. Once you have found if this is true then you can simply substitute the value in the second column. No need to use your second solution.

Comment: I posted the code.
Yes, maybe the 1st solution are enough but I can't write a code with it.

Comment: Before you add it, look thru `ListView1.Items` to see if whatever you dont want to duplicate exists.  If it does, just modify that item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the item before add it

```
If (ListView1.FindItemWithText(row(0)) Is Nothing) Then
    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
End If
```

Comment: It works. Thank you, but when I check the other radiobutton it's doesn't update the the row(1). Thank you again, I'm gonna try to add some codes in your suggested codes.

Comment: @James If you run in other problems just update this post and let me know with a comment in below this post. For now, if my answer had help you, please click on the "green check" below the "up down vote" on the left side of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out because of others help also.I created a function as Dictionary.This code is updating the subitem without adding or deleting item.

```
Dim thisDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

 Public Sub listviewupdate(ByVal D As Dictionary(Of String, String))
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    For Each KVP As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In D
        Dim LVI As New ListViewItem(KVP.Key)
        LVI.SubItems.Add(KVP.Value)
        ListView1.Items.Add(LVI)
    Next
End Sub

 Private Sub rbChoiceA_Checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim rbA As RadioButton = TryCast(sender, RadioButton)
    Dim str As String = rbA.Parent.Name.Remove(0, 6)
    lblItemNo.Text = str
    If thisDict.ContainsKey(str) Then thisDict.Remove(str)
    thisDict.Add(str, rbA.Text)
    listviewupdate(thisDict)
End Sub
```